# Do I have have to provide SSH key or name/password to Linux VM in Azure?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, terraform-provider-azure

An Ubuntu Linux VM had been set up in Azure with AAD login setting, Seems when I create the VM I have to provide SSH key or user name and password in the `os_profile_linux_config` within `azurerm_virtual_machine` resource. Otherwise I'll get an error (see the bottom part). The annoying thing for me is this is very inconsistent! Some times it ask for a SSH key/PW some times not.

When the time it do asked SSH key/PW, I can disable the SSH keys and the PW by remove the ssh_key config block and run the terraform script again, and not complain yields out. Again very Annoying.

I have AAD login set up, I see no point to use the SSH key or User password to login.

Why on Earth I have to set up a not-every-time-so-sure must-include-things and later on can be deleted?

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "openlr_webapp_vm" {
  ...
  os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = true
  }
}
```

Error message

> compute.VirtualMachinesClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request:
>   StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="InvalidParameter"
>   Message="Authentication using either SSH or by user name and password
>   must be enabled in Linux profile." Target="linuxConfiguration"

Comment: The feature is still in preview. So maybe this requirement will go away until GA?! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/login-using-aad You can also leave direct feedback on the bottom of that page

Comment: @silent But you think this has something to do with Manages a Virtual Machine by `azurerm_virtual_machine`? the AAD Linux login is done by `azurerm_virtual_machine_extension`

Comment: I don't know. you could try to deploy with ARM instead of Terraform to see if this behaves differently

Comment: Can I know the reason that you do not give any response? no mark, no more questions.

Answer (score 2):

> Do I have to provide SSH key or name/password to Linux VM in Azure?

The Ssh key and password are an alternative setting for Linux. You can see that the `admin_username` is required, but the password is required when it's Windows OS and you can use the SSH key instead of the password for Linux when you disable the password. It's designed by Azure.

In addition, the SSH key or password is set for SSH. Not necessary for Linux. For Azure VM, if you do not set the SSH key/password, then you cannot remote connect to the VM. And you also cannot use the VM like the local machine, such as install packages, test the applications. The VM extension can do something for you, but it also can do nothing when the agent is down.

So finally, the SSH key/password is set for the remote connection and is necessary.